# Permutation of a finite number of measurable functions is measurable?

Tags: measure-theory, reference-request

Let there be a finite number of measurable functions $\{f_i\}_{i=1}^n$ with common domains of definition. Is it then true that a permutation of these functions $\{h_i\}_{i=1}^n$ also measurable?

By permutation I mean that for every fixed element $x$ in the domain of definition of these functions, the values $\{f_i(x)\}$ are permuted and reassigned as $\{h_i(x)\}$.

Clearly, the case when the permutation is independent of $x$ is merely a permutation of the indices, whereas I am interested in the permutation of the values.

Are there any interesting results along these lines?

Comment: You need to assume that the permutation is measurable...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Say $E$ is a non-measurable set. Let $f_0=0$, $f_1=1$, $h_0=\chi_E$, $h_1=1-\chi_E$.